# Where to store the react query cache

Tags: react-query

Hello to everyone who knows where to store the react query cache ?.Is it possible to decide for yourself where the react query should store the cache ?

Answer (score 3):

react-query stores the cache in-memory. If you want to additionally sync the storage somewhere else, have a look at the [persistQueryClient plugin](https://react-query.tanstack.com/plugins/persistQueryClient).

Comment: When you say `in-memory` is that RAM or localStorage memory?

Comment: RAM. localStorage is a persistent storage in the browser ...